# getting difference between two invoices by ranking and subtracting one from the other

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to grab difference in invoices

Attempted using cte's for ranks 1 and 2, but they have a subquery in them and cant be done!

the second query looks the same, but with rank=2.

```
select *
from (

  SELECT i.id, i.subtotal/100 as subtotal, i.created_at, i.paid_at
  ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.subscription_id ORDER BY i.created_at DESC) AS Rank  
  From Invoices i

) as r
where r.rank = 1
order by r.created_at desc;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the path that you are on (using `row_number()`/`rank()`), you can use conditional aggregation.  Assuming you want the difference of the `subtotal`, then:

```
select sum(case when seqnum = 1 then subtotal
                else - subtotal
           end) as difference
from (select i.*, i.subtotal/100 as subtotal,
             row_number() over (partition by i.subscription_id order by i.created_at desc) as seqnum
      from Invoices i
     ) i
where seqnum in (1, 2)
order by r.created_at desc;
```